# How to import one namespace inside another in Typescript ( files used inside - ASP.NET Razor project )

Tags: javascript, asp.net, typescript

I have two namespaces

namespace1:

file1.ts

```
///<reference path="./file2" />
import * as NameSpace2 from './file2';
    export namespace namespace1 {

        export class Class1 {
            constructor(){}         
            public sayHello(){
            console.log("Hello");
            }
      
        }

    }
```

file2.ts

namespace 2:

export namespace namespace2 {

```
export class Class2 {
    constructor(){}         
    public sayHi(){
    console.log("Hi");
    }

}
```

}

I want to use the namespace 2 within 1.

After doing the above I got the error:

*Import declarations in a namespace cannot reference a module.*

Answer (score 0):

Use references in the file to let node know what to compile together

Add the includes in the .csproj

In the .ini file, add the bundle using registry. this will let you add the dependencies in other files.